# What started the multiverse collapse?

Tags: marvel, secret-wars, marvel-illuminati, new-avengers

In *New Avengers* #2, Reed Richards presents the crisis to the Illuminati.  He describes that the current issue with 'incursions' started when 'an event' occurred on a parallel Earth, which caused the premature death of that Earth's universe.  Since I don't read many Marvel comics, I'm wondering if I missed something that was detailed in another comic.

What happened to destroy that parallel Earth and its universe?  What was this 'event' that Richards refers to?

Answer (score 6):

#### The birth of "Rabum Alal" is believed to be the event which caused the death of the First Earth that was destroyed.

- Its destruction triggered the multiversal collapse indicative of incursions. This information is relayed by the enigmatic [Black Swan](http://marvel.wikia.com/Yabbat_Ummon_Turru_(Earth-TRN265)) (Yabbat Ummon Turru) to Reed Richards and the Illuminati.
- If you wish to have a more complete explanation, you can watch the video below created by comic enthusiasts at Retcon Punch. It is full of spoilers. You have been warned.

Answer (score -1):

Doom did it.  He learns that the beyonders are gonna blow up the multiverse for funsies, and decides to ruin the plan. By killing an iteration of the man that the beyonders seeded into every reality,  owen reece the molecule man, that universe is unmoored and destroyed, this causes the contraction that starts the incursions. So the Avengers and other players deal with and propigate from the incursions, doom is also destroying universes and taking molecule men to make his own bomb to kill all the beyonders with. Everything dies at more or less the same time and because Doom, Dr strange and 616 Owen Reece are present when the beyonders and reality dies, Owen becomes super god as he is part of all the destruction but undestroyed. He becomes all of the everything that was the multiverse, and is a bit unballanced and crazy, he becomes a tool to wield, and dr strange shys away from the task and doom becomes god.